# SVG element — handling and selecting text

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

having trouble solving a problem in d3 - i'm trying to append a legend to my svg, and the text i'm putting in it needs to be separated out so only the d.key is colored by the colorScale and the d.total is beneath the d.key and the fill is "black".

here's the line of code i was just referring to — `.text(function(d) { return (d.key) + ' (' + d.total + ')'; })`

in short, how can i add another line of text below d.key and make the fill of this new text "black" or just not the colorScale like d.key is colored with.

```js
svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "legend")
          .selectAll("text")
          .data(layers)
            .enter().append("text")
              .text(function(d) { return (d.key) + ' (' + d.total + ')'; })
              .attr('fill', function(d) { return colorScale(d.key); })
              .attr('y', function(d, i) { return 50 * (i + 2.75); })
              .attr('x', "375");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number of ways to do it.  Two separate `text` elements wrapped in a `g` or what I show below is two `tspan` wrapped in a a `text`:

```js
var svg = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', 500)
  .attr('height', 500);

var layers = [
  {
    key: 'one',
    total: 10
  }, {
    key: 'two',
    total: 20
  }
];

var colorScale = d3.scale.category10();

var text = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend")
  .selectAll("text")
  .data(layers)
  .enter().append("text")
  .attr('y', function(d, i) { return 50 * (i + 2.75); })

text.append("tspan")
  .text(function(d) { return (d.key) + ' (' + d.total + ')'; })
  .attr('fill', function(d) { return colorScale(d.key); })  
  .attr('x', "375");

text.append("tspan")
  .attr("dy", "1.2em")
  .attr("x", "375")
  .text("Second row of text")
  .style("fill", "black");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```